# Null value matching in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in a mysql database . Deseasetype(DTID,TypeName) , Symptom(SID, SymptomName, DTID) , Result(RID, SID1, SID2, SID3, result).1st two table, i think is clear enough.

In result table: there will be combination's of symtoms and any values of SymID1/ SymID2/ SymID3  can be null. here i send a picture of the table result.

[image]

I want to input some symptom and output will be the result from the 'Result' table. 
For that i wrote this query:

```
$query = "select Result from result where (result .SID1= '$symptom1') AND (result.SID2= '$symptom2' ) AND (result.SID3 = '$symptom3')";
```

This work only when three symptom's have value. but if any of the symptom's are null, then no result found. May be the query should be more perfect.

**please avoid any syntax error in my writing.

Comment: that output's multiple answeres. and not appropriate. @habib

Comment: What do you want to exactly retrieve from the result set ? What are posible values that you can pass as parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are comparing NULL to an empty string, and they aren't equal. You could try this instead:

```
SELECT Result
FROM symptom
WHERE IFNULL(symptom.SID1, '') = '$symptom1'
AND IFNULL(symptom.SID2, '') = '$symptom2'
AND IFNULL(symptom.SID3, '') = '$symptom3'
```

Notes:

- You need to correctly escape the values of $symptom1, $symptom2 and $symptom3.
- This won't efficiently use indexes.

Comment: This will require to change how the null value for a symptom is stored in the database. So if `NULL` is being stored then this query will return false if a single symptom passed is null.

Answer (score 0):

As mark pointed out, the query is eventually falling down to compare with null if you are not escaping the `null`.
Or you can slightly change your logic to show a empty symptom with value '0' and then using the [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function you can easily build your query.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$query = "select Result from  result
                        where (result.SID1 = '$symptom1' OR result.SID1 IS NULL) AND 
                              (result.SID2 = '$symptom2' OR result.SID2 IS NULL) AND 
                              (result.SID3 = '$symptom3' OR result.SID3 IS NULL)";
```